# Number of arrangement of letters of a given word whose vowels aren't consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many discrete ways can you arrange the word "challengers" if all the vowels should be separated with each other?

The total number of permutations is $\frac{11!}{2!2!}$ and I subtracted it with the total number of permutations when the vowels are together $\frac{3!}{2!} × \frac{9!}{2!}$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title "How many discrete ways does this have?" because it wasn't addressing the content of your question ; in particular the presence of the adjective "discrete" was disputable.

Comment: No. your second result isn't correct : you have considered only the case where the 3 vowels are grouped ; but you have to eliminate also the cases like "chaellngers" where you have a group of 2 vowels + an isolated one.

Comment: @Jean Marie then how should I solve it then?

Comment: Consider the different cases...

Answer (score 1):

How about we first arrange the consonants, there are $\frac{8!}{2!}$ ways of doing this. Then we choose where we are going to put the vowels, they can be between the consonants, be the first letter, or be the last letter, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways of doing this. Then from the $3$ vowel slots we pick, we choose which one will we put $a$ in, there are $3$ ways of doing this.

$$
\frac{8!}{2!}\times\binom{9}{3}\times 3
$$